# Hide associate model's data in sails

Tags: node.js, json, model, sails.js, waterline

I have two model
`Account.js` and `Content.js`

In `content.js` i have associated Account model like this

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    title: { type: "string" },
    description: { type: "string" },
    userId: { model: "account", required: true },
    categoryId: { model: "contentcategory" },
  },
};
```

In `account.js` model file
i have

```
    module.exports = {
      attributes: {
        fName: { type: "string" },
        lName: { type: "string" },
        pass: { type: "string", required: true },
        email: { type: "string", required: true, isEmail: true, unique: true },
        phone: { type: "number" },
        walletBalance: { type: "number", defaultsTo: 0 },
      },
};
```

When fetching the a content I get list of content that also includes account details.

```
{
    title:"category Name",
    description : "CAtegort Desc",
    userId : {
    id: 12552,
    fName:John,
    lName:Doe,
    pass : "23623562356",
    email:"john Doe",
    phone: "124151516",
    walletBalance: 234
    }
}
```

I want only the fname and lname of the user and hide pass, walletbalance etc, how can i do it sails waterline

Answer (score 0):

You have to use customToJSON as mentioned in the [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson).

with the following sentence to hide unwanted fields in account.js:

```
customToJSON: function () {
 return _.omit(this, ['pass', 'email', 'phone', 'walletBalance'])
},
```

Add it after model's attribute object.

Comment: is there a way i can hide them in content.js?, i may need email, phone when fetching from account (blueprint)